# Can't copy files to my iPad

Tags: nautilus, iphone, ipad, ios

I am able to connect iPad(mini 5, iOS 13.2.3) to my laptop(Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) and browse the files. But I can not copy a file to the iPad, Nautilus begins the copying process, which then gets stuck on 0%. `cp` doesn't work either, it simply freezes.

I suspect the problem was caused by the update to iOS 13, because it worked just fine before, but I'm not sure.

[Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194412/cant-copy-contents-to-my-ipad) was recently closed because the author wasn't using the official version of Ubuntu. Since my version is "official", I hope I can find some help.

I would appreciate any idea or workaround on how I could send files to my iPad without the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. It's broken for iOS 13.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1854403

Also check changelog https://cgit.libimobiledevice.org/libimobiledevice.git/log/